# How to change a 'keymaps_items' property using Python

Tags: python, properties, keymap

I try to change the properties value, but it's not working in the console:

```
 bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.default.keymaps['Object Mode'].keymap_items['object.delete'].properties['use_global'] = True
```

[image]

Answer (score -4):

I have solved this problem. In fact this code has been modified in blender's shortcuts and can be run in an external script, but you can't see the changes in real time with the console

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but this is not a clear answer at all.